# JavaScript cookie stores name but not colour

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have three functions, copied mostly from the W3schools tutorial. checkCookie, getCookie and setCookie.

The code works normally, when I only want to store the user's name but when I try to use the getCookie function to get the person's favourite colour, things go wrong. The program is meant for only storing the user's name: http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/25/    < working example. For TL;DR go to the bottom because the problem may be simple enough not to need to read the code.

Code from fiddle:

```
<script>
      function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var title = cname + "=";
    var cookie_array = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<cookie_array.length; i++) {
        var check = cookie_array[i];
        while (check.charAt(0)==' ') check = check.substring(1);
        if (check.indexOf(title) != -1) {
            return check.substring(title.length, check.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var name=getCookie("name");
    if (name != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + name);
    } else {
       name = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (name != null && name != "") {
           setCookie("name", name, 30);
       }
    }
}

function RemoveC() {

document.cookie = "name=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
} 

function Customise() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("Test");
     var name=getCookie("name");
    if (name != "") {
      elem.innerHTML = "Hi there, " + name;
    } else {
elem.innerHTML = "";      

    }

    }

</script>

<body onload="checkCookie(); Customise()">
    <button onclick="RemoveC()">Remove Cookie</button>

<p id="Test">


    </p>

</body>
```

I tried to amend the code to also store the users favourite colour. I changed the setCookie and checkCookie functions to the following:

```
    function setCookie(cname, ccolour, cvalue, cvalue2, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+ccolour+"="+cvalue2+"; "expires;
    }

function checkCookie() {
    var name=getCookie("name");
    if (name != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + name);
    } else {
       name = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
    var colorC = prompt("Please enter your favourite colour:","");
       if (name != null && name != "" && colorC != "" && colorC != null) {
           setCookie("name", "colour", name, colorC, 30);
       }
    }
}
```

I realise that there is a problem wit the beginning of the checkCookie function as in it only checks if the name is there and doesnt check that colour is there but I'm just testing at the moment.

I also changed the Customise function to get the colour and alert it to the user

```
 var Fcolour = getCookie("colour");
    alert(Fcolour);
```

Here is the fiddle for the new code that doesn't store colour properly: http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/28/

Now, nothing works. The checkCookie function doesn't run completely. I suspect there is a problem with me semicolons. I don't understand cookies very well. Can you store multiple values divided my ";"? like, name=test; colour=test; something=test; expdate.....